# Port 3306 for MySQL closed

Tags: mysql, debian

It seems that the port 3306 for remote MySQL access is closed on my server. In /etc/mysql/my.cnf I changed the bind-address setting to my remote IP already and restarted the server. A nmap scan of both localhost and my remote IP shows that it's still closed and only accessible from localhost though:

```
root@an0n:/etc/mysql/conf.d# nmap REMOTEIP 

Starting Nmap 5.00 ( http://nmap.org ) at 2015-04-09 20:30 MSK
Interesting ports on DOMAIN (REMOTEIP):
Not shown: 995 closed ports
PORT    STATE SERVICE
22/tcp  open  ssh
53/tcp  open  domain
80/tcp  open  http
139/tcp open  netbios-ssn
445/tcp open  microsoft-ds

Nmap done: 1 IP address (1 host up) scanned in 0.17 seconds
root@an0n:/etc/mysql/conf.d# nmap localhost

Starting Nmap 5.00 ( http://nmap.org ) at 2015-04-09 20:30 MSK
Warning: Hostname localhost resolves to 2 IPs. Using 127.0.0.1.
Interesting ports on localhost.localdomain (127.0.0.1):
Not shown: 992 closed ports
PORT     STATE SERVICE
22/tcp   open  ssh
25/tcp   open  smtp
53/tcp   open  domain
80/tcp   open  http
139/tcp  open  netbios-ssn
445/tcp  open  microsoft-ds
587/tcp  open  submission
3306/tcp open  mysql

Nmap done: 1 IP address (1 host up) scanned in 0.12 seconds
```

Where could I search now? I never used iptables by the way.

Comment: You can check the current iptables rules with `iptables -L` (please add the output)

Comment: Are the server behind NAT(It has a private IP), if so are you port forwarding port 3306 from the public IP to the private IP?

Comment: Can you update your question with the result for `netstat -anp` ?